# Unable to save game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, save

I'm try a few days to learn how to keep the data in the game

I want to keep a number for learn, but I do not understand why I can not

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Save 
{
    public int Cuens;
    void Update () 
    {
        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.T)) {
            Cuens += 5;
            SaveGame ();
        }
        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.Y))
            LodeGame ();
    }
    void SaveGame()
    {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter ();
        FileStream file = File.Create (Application.persistentDataPath + "/gamesave.save");
        Game save = new Game (Cuens);
        bf.Serialize (file, save);
        file.Close ();
        Debug.Log (save);
    }
    void LodeGame()
    {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter ();
        FileStream file = File.Open (Application.persistentDataPath + "/gamesave.save", FileMode.Open);
        Game save = (Game)bf.Deserialize (file);
        file.Close ();
        Debug.Log (save);
    }
}
```

Comment: What error you are getting? Please provide if you have any trace log or error log.

Comment: I do not get an error

Comment: Do you call void Update somewhere? because the script does not Extend MonoBehaviour to be called by the engine. Either extend  MonoBehaviour and put the script on a GameObject or make the Save and load methods public and call them from an other script.

Comment: Shouldn't `LodeGame` be `LoadGame`?

Comment: I added the script on GameObject but nothing happens

Comment: @dym111 Does your class extends MonoBehaviour? it should loo like public class Save : MonoBehaviour{

Answer (score 0):

When you load the game state from file you create a new Game object but never do anything with it:

```
 void LodeGame()
{
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter ();
    FileStream file = File.Open (Application.persistentDataPath + "/gamesave.save", FileMode.Open);
    Game save = (Game)bf.Deserialize (file);
    // you never do something with this
    file.Close ();
    Debug.Log (save);
}
```

A simple approach could be to write back the loaded data into your current `Game` object:

```
 void LodeGame()
{
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter ();
    FileStream file = File.Open (Application.persistentDataPath + "/gamesave.save", FileMode.Open);
    Game save = (Game)bf.Deserialize (file);
    file.Close ();
    this.Cuens = save.Cuens; // restore value.
    Debug.Log (save);
}
```